# Using a python list to execute commands in Linux

Tags: python, list

I'm facing a lot of mail migrations at work. To make this a little easier and to learn some more Python with a fun project I decided to code a Python script that is usable for everyone to use imapsync. I'm only a bit stuck here. This is a piece of the code that takes care of the usernames. The other variables are already specified earlier on in the code.

```
    userinput = input('Wat zijn de gebruikersnamen die verhuist worden van dit domein? Scheidt met een spatie: ')
user = userinput.split()
password1 = input('Welk wachtwoord wordt gebruikt?: ')
password2 = password1
for x in range(0, user):
    user1 = x  + '@' + domain
    imapsync = "screen -S mailmigratie -m imapsync --host1 " + host1 + " --ssl --host2 " + host2 + " --ssl2 --password1 " + password1 + " --password2 " + password2 + " --user1 " + user1 + " --user2 " + user1 + ">> imapsynclog" + user1 + ".txt"
    print("imapsync is nu gestart in een screen, er wordt een logfile gegenereerd")
    os.system(imapsync)
    print(user1)
```

I use the `print(user1)` function to check if the list prints it okay, but I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imapscript.py", line 82, in <module>
    for x in range(0, user):
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The first commenter kantal solved the issue. I have changed "for x in range(0, user):" to "for x in user:".

Comment: Instead of "for x in range(0, user):" write "for x in user:"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The issue is with your `user` variable I believe. As per the below line, `user` is supposed to be returning a list of strings.

```
user = userinput.split()
```

When used it in `range` like below

```
for x in range(0, user):
```

Here python interpreter was expecting that `user` as an integer but it is a list of strings, which is why the error is `TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Maybe you are looking for something like `range(0, len(user))` or `enumerate(user)`.

Please explore them for your learnings & I hope this helps.